# Is Ash's Pikachu stronger than regular Pikachu?

Tags: pokemon

Is Pikachu stronger than other Pikachu or his Pikachu special type Pokémon.

Comment: Of course, his pikachu is so strong that at Elite 4 level it still cannot beat a level 5 (starter) Chikorita :P.

Comment: Actually, [this answer](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/23383/why-does-team-rocket-always-try-to-catch-pikachu/23385#23385) does answer your question.

Comment: Ash's Pikachu has the [Power of Plot](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StrongAsTheyNeedToBe) **W**A**R**N**I**N**G**: TvTropes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By a regular Pikachu you mean by the anime standards? Then yes, it's above average.

But compared to Red's Pikachu from the manga it's a Magikarp.
In the manga, Red is one of the (if not THE) best trainers of the region. He actually uses his brain in combat. The Pokemon world in the manga is a lot harsher than the anime world (Pokemons are used as weapons to kill humans and other Pokemons). Ash would probably get destroyed by a random Ratata from the manga. So no, as per manga standards (it'd be one of the weakest).

Red's Pikachu is what I call a strong Pikachu. For instance, Red's Pikachu (very well trained, and very experienced in battles) has taken out all of Lance's (Elite Four) Pokemons in one megavolt attack. He's even made Lugia faint with that attack. And Red's Pikachu was about level 88 the last time I checked.

Source: Pokemon Manga and Pokemon Anime

Answer (score -1):

The pikachu itself is not special it is however pretty strong since it was trained a lot.

Comment: Please add some references to back up your claim and expand your answer.

Comment: its hard to find a reference where it says its a normal pikachu, but the absence of anything that says its a special pikachu